# Code composer studio: fatal error: could not open source file "types.h"

Tags: c++, code-composer

So I'm trying to compile a project in Code Composer Studio, but I get the error message:

"..\L138_aic3106_init.h", line 6: fatal error: could not open source file "types.h"
1 fatal error detected in the compilation of "../L138_aic3106_init.c".
Compilation terminated.

I've checked that types.h is inside the install directory and also updated the software.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. CCS is supposed to check inside the project and install directories, but for some reason wasn't finding the right file. I was using CCS inside a VM. which may cause some directory path issues. So I added the include explicitly by adding the file in the list under
Project->Properties-->Specify a preinclude file.

Another thing to try is to right click on the project name and click 'Properties'->'Add File;
Then add your .h file as a link.